# filter ACF choice field based on another choice field

Tags: wordpress, dropdown, advanced-custom-fields

just want to maniupulate my ACF fields in this way:
a first choice dropdown field (Island Choice) with these values

**Island Choice**

- Corfù
- Lefkada
- Zante

and then a second choice dropdown field (Island's locality) dynamically filtered based on one of the previuos Choice, in example

**if Corfù is selected then**

*Island's locality*

- Acharavi
- Gouvia
- Dassia

**if Lefkada is selected then**

*Island's locality*

- Nikia
- Nidri
- Poros

**if Zante is selected then**

*Island's locality*

- Laganas
- Blue Caves
- Navagio

I have found this documentation,

```
https://github.com/Hube2/acf-dynamic-ajax-select-example/tree/master/dynamic-select-example
```

but is not very clear to me how to implement this into my wordpress environment (I'm a senior IT but not so good with php) just want someone to give me a starting point..
many thanks

**FURTHER INFORMATIONS**

basically:

1. I have a wordpress site with a child theme and a deep customized
   functions.php file.
2. this functions.php I have added actions for
   create a custom post type called "accomodation".
3. next I have created a field group called "accomodation-fields".
4. Inside this group I have created two choice fields "Island Choice" and "Island's Locality" ,and as I wrote before I want the second field filtered by the first one.

Comment: Why are you using ACF for this purpose by the way? You can easily achieve this using custom post type with taxonomies.

Comment: From a simple json/jquery/ajax standpoint this is relatively easy to implement but since youre using Wordpress/ACF can you be more specific on your use case so I can better understand and try to help.

Comment: @danwebb I have added FURTHER IFORMATION below the topic

Comment: @OsamaIbrahim there are more other custom fields that are not manageable through taxnomies(like star rating, kind of accomodation etc) so I need one place to have all my fields and then filter the frontend with wp facets based on acf fields.

Comment: Is this an adequate starting point? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/dynamically-populate-a-select-fields-choices/

Comment: @danwebb unfortunately I have already read this but is really different, this says how to populate a choice based on something present already in the database(like a term or a saved value) what I'm trying is more similar to a filter in the dropdown

Comment: Since the github repo was updated relatively recently I would recommend reaching out to the author for some more guidance. It looks like you may be able to add the files from the repo to a custom plugin or child theme/theme root and load the PHP file into the functions.php and see if it allows you to dynamically filter in the ACF plugin UI

Answer (score 0):

Ok I didn't contact the developer cause I cannot find a contact button on github.. but it was simple.

1. the php file in the repository must be past into my functions.php
2. place the js somewere and edit the php file to retrieve the correct
   js path
3. import all json into acf and cptui to have the examples of
   the developer
4. fill some cities and states

done

it works perfectly with the newest ACF versions but of course this is only a starting point, I have to deep customize this code for my use.